# 3 Column to 2 Column. Multiple Rows

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So the problem I'm having is I have multiple rows with 3 columns in it. However; if I want to have smaller content width, I want it to drop to 2 column. How?

I also have to mention that each column contains image background. Every solution I've seen for this is to make 3rd column item 100% wide, however I can't do that with images. And is it even possible with CSS & HTML only.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

```
 <div class="media-row clearfix first">
        <div class="g6 first">
            Column 1
        </div>
        <div class="g6">
            Column 2
        </div>
        <div class="g6 last">
            Column 3
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="media-row clearfix last">
    <div class="g6 first">
        Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="g6">
        Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="g6 last">
        Column 3
    </div>
</div>

.media-row { margin-bottom: 20px; }
div.g6 { float: left; margin-left: 1.76%; min-height: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
div.g6:first-child { margin-left: 0 }
div.g6 { width: 27.91%; }
```

Comment: That should happen automatically.. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Emjdx/).

Comment: Edited with the code I use.

Comment: Don't use like that use as I shown in the above code..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the @media querys

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/nUhqT/)

you should find the break-points for your html
and make a rule like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    div.g6{
        width: 49%;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }     
}
```